# Total unit test execution time is gone

Tags: java, eclipse, unit-testing, junit

I have implemented automated system tests based on JUnit 4. It was always good to know how long a total test run took. The number of seconds was easy to get from the JUnit results window.

I have recently upgraded from Eclipse Luna SR 1 to Eclipse Luna SR 2 and it seems that they have removed the root node which had that summary information. It only displays individual results.

The console output does also not mention the overall test execution time.

Is there a way to get the old behavior back?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I discovered by accident, the information is not completely gone, it seems just not refreshed correctly in Eclipse Luna 4.4.2.

If I switch from the JUnit tab to somewhere else and then back to the JUnit tab, the information is displayed ("Finished after ... seconds"):

[image: JUnit, finished after 4080 seconds]